# How to skip invalid double quote character line in csv file using java?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a csv file contain 78400 lines (25MB).

When I read the csv file line by line, 1 column has error in 2nd line.

It contains backslash character.

When I read this column, it read all the remaining columns in the csv file as single column.

```
"CDE","456","6346","testdata2","MyData2","ClassB"
"ABC","123","4567\","testdata","MyData","ClassA"
"CDE","456","6346","testdata2","MyData2","ClassB"
```

How to skip that line by using line seperator in java?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your current code for reading and parsing this file.

Comment: Why not just fix the file?

Comment: In the current form it is not clear why the problem occurs. It must be located where you read the file. So please show us the `parsing step`. Do you use any libraries for parsing? How to you read columns? Do you separate by `,` or by `"..."`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openCSV then just define your parser with an escape character other than backslash.   If you don't want an escape character you can use the ICSVParser.NULL_CHARACTER or if you are using the 3.9 version of openCSV you can use the RFC4180Parser.

```
RFC4180ParserBuilder rfc4180ParserBuilder = new RFC4180ParserBuilder();
ICSVParser rfc4180Parser = rfc4180ParserBuilder.build();
CSVReaderBuilder builder = new CSVReaderBuilder(sr);
CSVReader reader = builder.withCSVParser(parser).build();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write method which would check by splitting the line into words and then identify the \ using as a char

```
String line=br.readline();
String words =line.split(",");
char[] word=words.toCharArray();
boolean escape=(word=='\');
```

You can identify the escape and handle it specially .